# Show UpdateProgress in update panel only when a particular event is occur

Tags: asp.net

I have an update panel which contains two buttons one is submit and other is cancel.

Now i want when i will click on submit button then progress bar displays.

But when i will click on cancel button it should not display.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <br />
                        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="PageUpdateProgress" DisplayAfter="0" >
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading...." /><br />
                            </ProgressTemplate>                            
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="lnk">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CssClass="lnk">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please help me i am tired to try to solve it.

Thanks ,Rajbir